# Installing Ruby with RVM in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, rvm

I installed RVM using the following command

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then I restarted the terminal and executed this commands

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
rvm install ruby
rvm use ruby --default
```

If I run this commands when I start the terminal I get ruby 2.1.2 as the default ruby version, but if I restart the terminal and I run

```
ruby -v
```

I get the following message

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you check if your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` have been modified by the RVM installer? They should, but there could have been something wrong with the installation (and honestly, I find RVM's instructions and installation procedure *very* confusing.)

If you want RVM to always be loaded on shell startup, you should put its initialization commands into your shell's configuration file. For Bash under Ubuntu (or any Linux), that'd be `~/.bashrc`. On other operating systems, such as OS X, you'd rather put it in `~/.bash_profile`.

You could try adding the commands by calling the following, mentioned in [this blog post](http://sirupsen.com/get-started-right-with-rvm/):

```
cd ~
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> .bashrc
```

Then, restart your shell, and RVM should be sourced.

Answer (score 0):

I followed original posters steps and verified my .bashrc and .bash_profile.

You need to make sure your running bash shell as a /bin/bash --login.

Usually there is a setting to run all commands as login. My rvm had all the correct information in the .bashrc and .bash_profile, but I was still seeing version 1.8 ruby.

After editing the terminal profile and restarting terminal, my version of ruby showed up as latest.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
First, open `~/.bashrc` to edit it.

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc # or
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following path in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH="-bash: /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin:/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@global/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin:/home/codie/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/codie/.rvm/bin"
```